# Multi Request Causing data inconsistency

Tags: spark-java

Currently i have a service post exposed using spark which will further call spring crud webservices.
Now when multiple requests more than 20-30 hits at same time i see the data been swaped something of thread issue sort. Could you please help me understand how spark handles this.

```
Spark.post("/testService", (request, response) -> {
        TestProcessor testProcessor = new TestProcessor();
        return testProcessor.inboundProcessing(request, lookupCache);
    });
```

above is the code which is used